# Applying OptaPlanner for VRP with customized transportation network

Tags: optaplanner, vehicle-routing

In short - does OptaPlanner require integration with mapping products, e.g. google maps or openstreet maps?

I am researching options for incorporating VRP optimization into a product feature set. The use case is to optimize the routing of construction vehicles on large job sites. In nearly all cases, there will be no roads or streets to act as the network on a site, so the network would need to be manually defined according to the 'roads' that exist on the site. Is this a use case that OptaPlanner supports?

Have not tried any code yet. Still researching.

Comment: Try one of [the vehicle routing quickstarts](https://github.com/TimefoldAI/timefold-quickstarts/tree/stable/use-cases). The quickstarts just use eucledean distance (not road distance).

Answer (score 0):

Neither OptaPlanner (nor [Timefold](https://timefold.ai/blog/2023/optaplanner-fork/)) really require any kind of network. They require a distance matrix between locations, and it doesn't even matter to the algorithm if the "distances" are in units of time, length or any other.

You could consider that a benefit (or a shortcoming) of the fact that neither of these tools bring any out-of-the-box integration with any map data provider.